# How to take action (measure) if error occurs while running Python file (.py)

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a python file, but running it frequently makes error because this program fetches information from websites, and sometimes instability of that websites causes error.

So, I'd like to write a line of code in that python file, as an alternative action, which will be run if any error occurs during execution of the python file.

I'm newbie to python, so only solution I can think of is using try ~ except snippet; 
cram all the codes into try: ,  and writing alternative actions in case of error in except: .

for example:

```
import selenium, time, os, sys ......

#needed variables are defined..
try:
    #about 300 lines of code are written

except: 
    print "Error occured while running program"
    driver.quit() #needed alternative action
```

But, I believe there will be much better way to do this.

I am using selenium(you don't have to know what it is), and I activate a variable named driver and when all works are finished, I have to close the driver by driver.quit() before execution of the python file is done. And even if any error occurs while running the program, the driver must be closed before quitting the program, no matter what.

I think putting all the existing codes in try:  is inefficient, somewhat ignorant, and spacing 4 times before every line of code takes a lot of time.

The alternative action should be written in the same python file. Could you help me?

Comment: You're catching exceptions correctly. One suggestion is to use specific exception names eg. TypeError, ValueError etc. in your except statement and perform specific actions based on which error occurred. Please refer to the python docs for more info on error handling and examples: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. try ~ except is a good way, but I want to use somewhat more .... convenient way. I mean, spacing 4 times before every line of code takes a lot of time and inefficient. Is there any other way to take action, by catching error happened no matter what part of my code made an error?

Comment: You should use `try`/`except` just for those lines where error might occurs, not for the complete code. Could you share code lines and the exact error log?

Comment: @이해주 take a lot of time if you do it one by one, but in any editor that is worth its salt you can do it for as many lines as you want at once

Comment: @Andersson the part that makes error is which clicks a button. But the button is loaded slowly, and instantly trying to click the button right after the page is being loaded makes error. Even though I use WebdriverWait, Sometimes the code cannot locate the button and eventually makes an error. Even that error happens, driver.quit() should be run. But, using `try: clickbutton except: driver.quit()` always fall into `except: driver.quit()` and driver is quit always, because at first time when page is loaded, the butten is still not loaded. it always takes time to load the button.

Comment: why not use a test framework and use a teardown method to quit the driver?  that is what most people would do.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Thankyou for your comment. I've seen people using test framework. Are there several python test frameworks? If there are, what would you recommend for selenium?

Comment: @이해주, I guess you're using `ExplicitWait` (`WebdriverWait`) not properly. Share exception log so I can help you to get rid of those errors... Also, if you want to use test framework, you can look toward http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/

Comment: @이해주 for test frameworks: I would start with unittest (it comes with python).  pytest is another great choice.